# Firefox ignoring response header content-range and playing only the sample sent

Tags: firefox, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have built an audio stream for `mp3` files, and each time client hits the audio it receives something like this:

[image]

But what it does is just plays 1 minute sample instead of 120 minute

[image]

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure because you didn't provide code or an example stream to test, but your handling of HTTP range requests is broken.

In your example request, the client sends `Range: bytes=0-`, and your server responds with a 1MiB response:

- `Content-Length: 1048576` (aka. 1 MiB)
- `Content-Range: 0-1048575/...`

This is wrong, the client did not request this! It did request `bytes=0-`, meaning all data from position 0 to the end of the entire stream (See the [http 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35)), i.e. a response equal to one without any `Range`. (IIRC, Firefox still sends the `Range: bytes=0-` to detect if the Server handles ranges in the first place).

This, combined with the `Content-Length`, leads the client (Firefox) to think the whole resource is just 1MiB in size, instead of the real size. I'd imagine the first 1 MiB of your test stream comes out as 1:06 of audio.

PS: The `Content-Duration` header (aka. RFC 3803) is something browsers don't usually implement at all and just ignore.

Comment: Just an idea. Did anyone tried someof the http 3xx header?'retry-after:1' and '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable' headers. This mimic max execution time exceeded.

Comment: FWIW, IE+Edge and Chrome all work fine when the server responds with less than requested - they simply issue another request to continue where the response left off. This in turn makes it possible to implement video streaming in frameworks like Rails without a long-running connection tying up a process. If the source of the stream is a file, putting something like nginx in front can solve the issue, but if it's dynamically created, it can't.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Did you tried some of the http 3xx header like:
'308 Resume Incomplete' or '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable' plus 'retry-after:2' or '413 Request Entity Too Large' plus 'retry-after:2'