# Break down Range Request

Tags: php, apache, request, range, partial

I like to response with video files and send ranges if requested.
A typical range-request from client/browser side is Range: bytes=0- which is finally a request for the hole file. But that is not the sense of a range request.

So I tried to send back a limited length of 1MB:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content
Content-Range: bytes 0-1048575/46137344
Conten-Length: 1048576
```

This work like a charm with Chrome.
Chrome's next request is

```
Range: bytes=1048576-
```

But Fire Fox don't come back to ask for further bytes and plays only the first MB of the video.

My question: **Is there a possibility to break down the Content-Range response of the requested range ?**

Comment: When you make a request with `Range: bytes=0-`, you are requesting for the entire file, not just 1 MB and as the response `Conten-Length` is 1 MB, Firefox thinks it's done after receiving 1 MB. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24357749/2745300

Comment: @kums Do you agree that such a request don't need a range request? Some say FF is asking the server whether range is supportet, but I'd already sent specific header. I asked for a possibility to fragment the response.

Comment: Is the Range header hard-coded or something dynamically sets it?

Comment: @kums Thanks for rely!! It's a PHP script which gets/sets the headers and delivers the content in case. [More practical than here](http://www.tuxxin.com/php-mp4-streaming/)