# ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"] is always null in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, webforms

I've written a file handler which reads blob from MS Sql Server and send it to the user browser.

My handler now supports "206 Partial Content" and it works fine in Chrome or even VlC Player.
Unfortunately it doesn't work with FireFox and IE and the reason is`ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"]` is always null in Firefox and IE.

and I always send this header to response:

```
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Is your implementation of accept-range correct ([\[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24357749/11683), [\[2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18745164/11683))?

Comment: I think yes. I've mentioned how I sent Accept-Ranges.